# How to setState from another Class - react

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm, react-redux

I am new to `react`. I am using this `function` in `ClassA`

```
clearClasses(){
    console.log("HIIIIII")
    this.setState({
        classNames: ['', '', '', '']
    })
```

I want to call this `function` in `ClassB` but tried to call that function like this,

Here's the Code in `ClassB`:

```
import ClassA from './ClassA.jsx';

new ClassA().clearClasses()
```

It works. But I can't set State. How to solve this problem. Please help me with some solutions.

Error Image:
[image]

Comment: Is this the actual application code? Do you mind sharing a bit more of your code?

Comment: Can you share your dom